# Detect if site has an RSS/Atom feed?

Tags: ios, nsurl

I have an URL for the site but not for it's feed(s), which I want to parse.

How to 
detect if site has an RSS/Atom feed(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" link in the head section of the site's defalut page:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://someurl/feed/" />
  <title>Some title</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to download default page? Is it always index.htm?

Comment: That would be the page you get when you, for example, try to download the page http:&#47;/stackoverflow.com/ over port 80. It may have any name, since that is usually configurable in the web server.

Comment: In addition, for ATOM check for type="application/atom+xml"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this question [How to check if a site has rss feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450501/how-to-check-if-a-site-has-rss-feeds)
you need to download the page and check for a rel='alternate'.

You could also have a fallback to regex the page for any mention of a feed.xml or similar, should the first parse fail, if you want to be sure to find any possible link to a RSS/Atom. This would not be as certain to contain the RSS of the actual page, it could be a link to an outside RSS.